# Does this sequence of functions converge uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Let $h_n : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ Such that $h_n(x) = 1 − nx$ if $0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{n}$  and $h_n(x) = 0$ if $\frac{1}{n}$ if $\frac{1}{n} \leq x \leq 1.$ Determine if $h_n$ converges uniformely

In this case, we note that it doesn't converge uniformly since the $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} 1-nx = 1$ when $0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{n}$, but $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} 0 = 0$ when $\frac{1}{n} \leq x \leq 1$ Hence we have two different limits. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: No. You have to be careful when taking the limit of n.. you can't do it while saying at the same time that 0<x<1/n. If you fix x and THEN take the limit of n then you get that the POINTWISE limit is the zero function. Regarding the uniform convergence I'll provide a hint: Try the definition (with the sup) and take x=1/(2n). Does the sup go to zero when n goes to infinity?

Comment: Not exactly. When you say "$\lim 1-nx=1$ when $0\leq x\leq\frac1n$", it makes no sense, since here we send $n\to\infty$, the range of $x$ should be irrelevant to $n$.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in comments the statement $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 - nx ) =1 $ for $0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1/n$ is specious.

A valid argument is, for fixed $x \in (0,1]$ and $N$ such that $1/N < x$, we have $h_n(x)=0$ for all $n \geqslant N$.  For $x=0$ we have $h_n(0) = 1$. Thus $h_n$ converges pointwise to $h$ where $h(0) =1$ and $h(x) = 0$ for $0 < x \leqslant 1$.  Since $h$ is discontinuous and each $h_n$ is continuous, convergence cannot be uniform.

Alternatively, after establishing that the pointwise limit is $h(x)$ (above), we have

$$|h_n(x) - h(x)| = \begin{cases}0, & x = 0 \\ |1 - nx|, & 0 < x \leqslant 1 \end{cases}$$

Thus, for $n> 1$ we have $\sup_{x \in [0,1]}|h_n(x) - h(x)| = n -1$.  Since the limit of this supremum is not $0$, convergence is not uniform.